# Different results with the same query in oracle 11g and 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

The query does not give the same results in oracle 10g and oracle 11g:

```
    with table1 as
 (select 1 as id, 'A' as col1, 'X' as col2
    from dual
  union all
  select 2 as id, 'Y' as col1, 'A' as col2
    from dual
  union all
  select 3 as id, 'Z' as col1, 'Z' as col2
    from dual)
select *
  from table1
 where (1 = 1 and (ID=2 or ID=3))
    or EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM dual WHERE col1 = 'A')
    or EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM dual WHERE col2 = 'A')
```

result in oracle 11g:

```
ID  COL1    COL2
1   A       X
2   Y       A
```

[image]
result in oracle 10g:

```
ID  COL1    COL2
1   A       X
2   Y       A
3   Z       Z
```

[image]
why???

Comment: pls share also the execution plans.

Comment: could you please build a sqlfiddle example?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior under 11g2 (11.2.0.3), I get all records.

Comment: On Oracle 11g its working and giving the all the rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/11165

Comment: Same on 11.2.0.4 and [11.2.0.2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/11164). Which version and patch level of 11g do you see this? I imagine you're hitting a bug in an earlier version.

Comment: I also cannot replicate on 11g (11.2.0.2). I get all records returned.

Comment: 11g  : Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit

Comment: 10g :Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit

Comment: There are a few bugs that could be then; 10407959 looks potentially feasible. Your best bet is probably to patch up, if you can't rework your real query to avoid the problem. Or raise an SR if you don't think it's a known issue, but I suspect they'll tell you to patch up first anyway.

Comment: I tried the query on 10g (XE and Enterprise), 11g (XE and Enterprise), 12c and everywhere got the same result (all the three rows). So it seems as not reproduceable in common case. Maybe there is "a magic setting" on and you should try the query on a new installation. Please add some info about your DB instance (SELECT * FROM V$INSTANCE) to the question. Also, I'd like to know if the problem remains when changing alias `id` to something different, for example `my_id`.

Comment: Can't reproduce in 11.2.0.4 nor 12.1.0.2. It might be a bug as somebody already suggested above.

Comment: What does the '1=1' criteria do ?

Comment: What happens if you changed "(ID=2 or ID=3)"  to "ID IN (2,3)" ?

Comment: Tested in Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit, I get all 3 records

Comment: Are you using hints on your real query? I got a similar problem some years ago, when the usage of a hint (indicating the index to be used) whas changing the resulting set...